# How to graph a function in iOS-charts

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts, non-linear-regression, best-fit-curve

I am using the iOS-charts library in (Swift 3) to plot my data into a scatter chart. I have a scatter chart and now would like a line chart to display a non-linear best fit line from the scatter data. Does the charts library have any easy functions for finding a non-linear best fit line, and if not how do I create a line from a function if a have to derive the best fit line function myself. I know how to create a line graph from data points but do not know if charts allows you to make one from a function. An example of what I'm trying to do is below. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Link to iOS-charts
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

[image]

Comment: hi Quinn, Were you able to find the ans to plot  best fit line graph..? I need to achieve something similar as linear best fit graph in scattered graph. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.